# MySql GROUP BY Max Date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, max

I have a table called `votes` with 4 columns: `id`, `name`, `choice`, `date`.


****`id`****`name`****`vote`******`date`***

****`1`*****`sam`*******`A`******`01-01-17`

****`2`*****`sam`*******`B`******`01-05-30`

****`3`*****`jon`*******`A`******`01-01-19`

My ultimate goal is to count up all the votes, but I only want to count 1 vote per person, and specifically each person's most recent vote.

In the example above, the result should be 1 vote for A, and 1 vote for B.

Here is what I currently have:

```
select name,
    sum(case when uniques.choice = A then 1 else 0 end) votesA,
    sum(case when uniques.choice = B then 1 else 0 end) votesB
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, choice, max(date)
    FROM votes
    GROUP BY name
) uniques;
```

However, this doesn't work because the subquery is indeed selecting the max date, but it's not including the correct `choice` that is associated with that max date.

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: votesA--1.......votesB--1.... I'm only including `name` in the select for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think "group by" to get the most recent vote.  Think of join or some other option.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT v.name,
       SUM(v.choice = 'A') as votesA,
       SUM(v.choice = 'B') as votesB
FROM votes v
WHERE v.date = (SELECT MAX(v2.date) FROM votes v2 WHERE v2.name = v.name)
GROUP BY v.name;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/155814/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: When I try this, I'm getting: `unknown column v.name in WHERE clause.`

Comment: `name` is in the `votes` table according to your question, so the column should be there.

Comment: Sorry, it was because I was just trying to see what the subquery did. I'm not quite sure what to make of the output of your query. It's a table with 3 columns: name, votesA, votesB. So it's including sam's vote for A and also sam's vote for B.

Comment: @Sam . . . Does not, as the SQL Fiddle demonstrates.  I don't know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: With MYSQL_FULL_GROUP_BY (introduced in 5.7 and 8.0), this is no more working. However, if you move the `GOUP_BY v.name` in subquery it works again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer are close but need to `JOIN` self

Subquery get `Max` date by name then `JOIN` self.

```
select
    sum(case when T.vote = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) votesA,
    sum(case when T.vote = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) votesB
FROM (
    SELECT name,Max(date) as date
    FROM T
    GROUP BY name
) AS T1 INNER JOIN T ON T1.date = T.date
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2504a/30)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    choice,
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    votes v
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            max(date)
        FROM
            votes
        GROUP BY
            name
    ) tmp ON
    v.id = tmp.id
GROUP BY
    choice;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
name,
sum( case when choice = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) voteA,
sum( case when choice = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) voteB
from
(
select id, name, choice
from votes
where date = (select max(date) from votes t2 
                where t2.name = votes.name ) 
) t
group by name
```

Or output just one row for the total counts of VoteA and VoteB:

```
select 
sum( case when choice = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) voteA,
sum( case when choice = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) voteB
from
(
select id, name, choice
from votes
where date = (select max(date) from votes t2 
                where t2.name = votes.name ) 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (if you really need count only last vote of person)

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when vote='A' then cnt else 0 end) voteA,
  sum(case when vote='B' then cnt else 0 end) voteB
FROM 
 (SELECT vote,count(distinct name) cnt
  FROM (
      SELECT name,vote,date,max(date) over (partition by name) maxd
      FROM votes
  ) 
  WHERE date=maxd
  GROUP BY vote
 )
```

PS. MySQL v 8

Answer (score 0):

Based on @d-shish solution, and since introduction (in MySQL 5.7) of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, the `GROUP BY` statement must be placed in subquery like this :

```
SELECT v.`name`,
    SUM(v.`choice` = 'A') as `votesA`,
    SUM(v.`choice` = 'B') as `votesB`
FROM `votes` v
WHERE (
    SELECT MAX(v2.`date`) 
    FROM `votes` v2 
    WHERE v2.`name` = v.`name` 
    GROUP BY v.`name` #           << after
) = v.`date`
# GROUP BY v.`name`               << before
```

Otherwise, it won't work anymore !